# Dispose ReportViewer object

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

How to Dispose ReportViewer object safely if application closed unexpectedly

```
 Public Shared rv As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer
```

Comment: If application gets closed, instance will be destroyed anyhow. Why are you worrying about it's disposal?

Comment: If application close unexpectedly then application gives an error `Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015 `
This error occur when `rv ` is not disposed
@RohitVats

Comment: See if posted answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about issue mentioned [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522208/wpf-app-with-reportviewer-gets-error-while-unloading-appdomain-exception-on-termination).

As mentioned in the link, you need to manually `Dispose()` the reportViewer instance on form closing event.

```
private void frmMyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     if (rv != null && !rv.Disposing && !rv.IsDisposed)
     { 
         rv.Dispose();
     }
}
```

OR

Either calling `reportViewer.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain()` in form closing event:

```
private void frmMyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    rv.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();         
}
```